# Google Cloud Data Flow - Timestamp error while trying a template JDBC flow from pgSQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are trying out Cloud Dataflow and ran a pipeline using the template JDBC - BigQuery. Our source database is PostgreSQL and the table has a few timestamp columns. However, the pipeline fails with the following message:

*"Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 1636156800000000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999]; error in writing field date_actual",      "reason" : "invalidQuery"*

Is this an issue with the postgreSQL driver returning a higher precision timestamp value or with the dataflow product?

Please note that the same table loads into bigquery just fine using a simple Cloud Data Fusion pipeline.

Thanks.

Comment: That timestamp is invalid. That translates to the year 51,882

Comment: Can you explain where that number comes from?

Comment: The number appears in the log, the source PostgreSQL has a column of timestamp data type and contains valid entries from this year. I am not trying to do anything special, a simple flow from postgreSQL to BigQuery. The problem is, the template flow for JDBC - BigQuery does not work for postgreSQL if it has timestamp columns, So my best guess is the precision at which the postgres timestamp value is being returned is different from what BQ expects. This seems to be a bug.